# phing with phpdoc2 doesn't run

Tags: hudson, jenkins, phing, zend-server, phpdoc

So I have a jenkins job to update a copy of my code and generate the phpdoc for my library, this is all done with phing

When I use these line in de build.xml it generates jsut fine (but with phpdocumentor 1.4.4)

```
<target name="phpdoc">
        <echo msg="PHP Documentor..." />
        <phpdoc title="API Documentation"
                destdir="/var/www/corelib"
                sourcecode="yes"
                output="HTML:Smarty:PHP">
            <fileset dir="./library/Core">
                <include name="**/*.php" />
            </fileset>
        </phpdoc>
    </target>
```

I want to use the new version of phpdocumentor so i installed it with pear

```
pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor-alpha
```

But when I run this command (I found this in the phing docs), jenkins prints "PHP documentor" and then directly marks the build as failed

```
<target name="phpdoc">
        <echo msg="PHP Documentor..." />
        <phpdoc2 title="API Documentation"  destdir="/var/www/corelib" template="responsive">
            <fileset dir="./library/Core">
                <include name="**/*.php" />
            </fileset>
        </phpdoc2>
    </target>
```

I have zendserver installed on this server but that can't be a problem because phpdoc 1.4.4 runs fine

So how do i solve this?

Comment: What output does the console log show?

Comment: i forgot about this issue, but i will post the solution as an answer (i had it fixed at the irc channel of phpdocumentor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution, so i post it for future reference

With some help of the people on the irc channel of phpdocumentor

so this a bug with the latest build of phing in combination with the latest version of phpdocumentor. To fix this problem just revert the instalation of phpdocumentor2 to this version

`phpDocumentor 2.0.0a3`

This will fix the problem with phing and the documentation gets generated with no problem